# Detecting which properties have been changed from two objects

Tags: javascript, performance

I have the following code. Providing two objects `cmd` and `this.xxx.properties`, script detects the only property changed and mutate the input object (`cmd`).

Script works fine but I would like to know if I could optimize or improve my code for speed.

```
    _deltaProperties: function (cmd) {

        var dataBefore = this.xxx.properties,
            newData = {};
        for (var prop in cmd.properties) {
            var newValue = cmd.properties[prop],
                oldValue = dataBefore[prop];
            if (newValue !== oldValue) {
                newData[prop] = cmd.properties[prop];
            }
        }
        cmd.properties = newData;
        return cmd;
    },
```

Comment: Can you clarify what needs to be returned/accomplished? At the moment the input is mutated and then also returned. Do you need a list of changed properties OR do you need to mutate the input to only contain the changed properties?

Comment: I need to mutate the input to only contain the changed properties. Thanks for your time on this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a bit of testing on jsperf which seems to indicate that it would be marginally faster for you to delete the properties you don't need rather than create a new object and replace it. Obviously, your mileage may vary. My test was objects with 6 properties, 3 of which were different.

**EDIT** : Delete is faster on IE. The new object version is faster on Chrome and FF.

```
_deltaProperties: function (cmd) {
    var prop;
    for (prop in cmd.properties) {
        if (cmd.properties[prop] === this.xxx.properties[prop]) {
            delete cmd.properties[prop];
        }
    }
    return cmd;
},
```

If you decided to keep your current code, there are some improvements you could make in terms of styling:

```
// I personally dislike underscores in variable names
deltaProperties: function (cmd) {
    // JavaScript only has function scope, a lot of developers define all 
    // variables at the top of the function - can help with subtle scope bugs
    var dataBefore = this.xxx.properties,
        newData = {},
        prop,
        newValue,
        oldValue;

    for (prop in cmd.properties) {
        newValue = cmd.properties[prop],
        oldValue = dataBefore[prop];
        if (newValue !== oldValue) {
            // Use newValue rather than accessing member again
            newData[prop] = newValue;
        }
    }
    cmd.properties = newData;
    return cmd;
},
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, could you please post your jsperf  link?

Comment: @GibboK - http://jsperf.com/delete-vs-new-object-code-review/3. Having just looked again I read the chart the wrong way round... fail. Your original method is faster on Chrome and FireFox but the delete method is marginally faster on IE.